# Rotating two images with linkprop

Tags: matlab, rotation

I want to rotate two images(handles.axes6 and handles.axes7) by linking them using linkprop. But I do not want to use 'CameraPosition' property to link them. Is there any other way to link them?

Comment: would `linkaxes` do the job for you?

Comment: No because I am dealing with 3d not 2d. I am at a loss on how to do this.

Comment: Why do you not want to `linkprop` on `'CameraPosition'`? It seems like that would do exactly what you want.